# Building a Python dice game, stuck on the last function? (CLOSED)

Tags: python, dice

At school we're creating a dice game for Python, and I can't seem to figure out how to finish this last function. In the game, Ezee, you have 14 dice, and you have to roll all of them. You have to take the mode of the dice and you reroll all the die that aren't the mode until all the die are the same number. Once they are all the same, you've won the game. This specific function is supposed to count the number of rolls,  and after using the command "game(debug=True)", return the number of rolls it took to win as well as reroll the die until you’ve won, as shown below:

```
In []: game()
Out[]: 18
In []: game(debug=True)
Out[]: [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 5, 5, 4, 4]
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 6]
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5]
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
       4
```

I have 8 functions besides that one that I have already completed:

```
import random 
def roll_die(): 
    ''' Return a random number 1-6
    ''' 
    dice = random.randint(1, 6)
    return dice

def first_roll(): 
    ''' Return a list of 14 numbers, each random 1 to 6
    '''
    rolls = [] #Initialize
    counter = 0
    while counter<14:
        #Append
        rolls.append(roll_die())
        counter = counter+1
    return rolls #Report/use

def count_frequency(dice, number):
    ''' dice is a list of fourteen ints
    number is an int
    returns the frequency of the number among elements of dice
    '''
    frequency = 0 #Initialize
    for die in dice:
        #Accumulate
        if die == number: 
            frequency=frequency+1
    return frequency #Report/use

def find_mode(dice): 
    ''' Accepts a list of numbers 1-6.
    Returns the most common number in the list.
    Returns one of the most common if there is a tie.
    '''
    #Start with a record that will be beat
    record = 0
    for number in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]: 
        # Check for the record breaker
        frequency=count_frequency(dice, number)
        if frequency>record:
           record = frequency # Set the new record
           mode = number
    return mode


def list_unmatched_dice(dice, target): 
    '''Accepts dice    ::a list of numbers.
               target  ::a number
    Returns the indices where the element != target
    '''
    #for each index in range(14) if dice[index] != mode then add index to the new list
    unmatched = []
    for index in range(14):
        if dice[index] != target:
           unmatched.append(index)
    return unmatched

def reroll_one(dice, index): 
    ''' dice is a list of 14 numbers
    index is an int 0-13
    Return the list of dice, with a number randomly chosen 
    from 1 to 6 to replace the item at index
    '''
    #reroll the dice
    dice[index]=roll_die()
    return dice

def reroll_many(dice):
    ''' accepts a list of 14 numbers
    returns resulting list of 14 numbers
    '''
    #reroll the die
    mode=find_mode(dice)
    index=list_unmatched_dice(dice, mode)
    for index in list_unmatched_dice(dice, mode):
        dice=reroll_one(dice, index)
    return dice

def won(dice): 
    '''dice is a list of 14 ints 1-6
    checks for 14 of a kind
    returns True or False
    '''
    #Start with a record that will be beat
    if dice == [dice[0]]*14:
        #Check for the record breaker
        match = True
    else:
        match = False
    return match #Set the new record
```

I know all the other functions are correct because I've tested them out and they work fine, but does anyone have any idea how I complete this last one? Here is the starter code I was given to use:

```
def game(debug=False): 
    '''rolls 14 dice and repeats until getting an Ezee
    returns the number of rolls made.
    '''
    dice = first_roll()
    if debug:
        print dice
    # Anything else to do before you start iterating?
    while not won(dice):
        # What to do if you haven't won?
    # What to do once you've won?
```

And here is the code I have so far:

```
def game(debug=False): 
    '''rolls 14 dice and repeats until getting an Ezee
    returns the number of rolls made.
    '''
    #Initialize
    dice = first_roll()
    target = find_mode(dice)
    rolls = 0
    if debug:
        print dice
    while won(dice):
        rolls=rolls+1
        if list_unmatched_dice(dice, target) == find_mode(dice):
            return rolls #Report/use
    while not won(dice):
        #Accumulate
        rolls=rolls+1
        if list_unmatched_dice(dice, target) != find_mode(dice):
            return rolls
```

Could anyone possibly help me out and tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've been trying for a while to figure this out and I'm pretty confused. Your responses will do a great deal for me, thank you so much!

Comment: What is wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: When I run it it says the number of times I've rolled the die is 1, even if I've rolled it more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it like that:

```
def game(debug=False): 
    '''rolls 14 dice and repeats until getting an Ezee
    returns the number of rolls made.
    '''
    dice = first_roll()
    if debug:
        print dice
    counter = 0
    while not won(dice):
        counter += 1
        reroll_many(dice)
        if debug:
            print dice

    print counter


if __name__ == '__main__':
    game()
```

Comment: Oh, that seems like it's close! The only problem is instead of just giving me the number of times rolled it gives me a list of numbers. Also, I don't think it's going off of the mode.

Comment: show your output and check the right spaces in line with print function. it must be out of the while loop!

Comment: 'In: game()
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13'

Comment: recheck last print! it stays in while loop. if u show your code i can point a mistake you do or del 4 space in last print line